# Solve $\int_{\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2}}^a 1-\frac{2 \sqrt{x^2-\frac{3}{4}a^2}}{a} dx$

Tags: calculus

As part of a probability question I am trying to solve this integral:

$$\int_{\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2}}^a 1-\frac{2 \sqrt{x^2-\frac{3}{4}a^2}}{a} \mathrm dx$$

But am stuck. help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just write $\frac{2}{a}\cdots$.

Comment: $x=\frac{\sqrt3 a}{2}\sec t$.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{8} a \left(4-4 \sqrt{3}+\ln 27)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use the substitution $x={\sqrt 3\over 2}a\cosh u$ for $a>0$ and $x=-{\sqrt 3\over 2}a\cosh u$ for $a<0$.